# ASP.NET: GRIDVIEW: How to strikeout the entire text in a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to strikeout the entire text(even the whitespace between text/cells) in a row in the RowDataBound event of the GridView.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C#

on RowDataBound event

```
e.Row.Style.Value = "text-decoration:line-through;"
```

this is how your GridView will be rendered, it works !

```
<table>
<tr style="text-decoration:line-through;">
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-decoration:line-through;">
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-decoration:line-through;">
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: didn't work for me, maybe some other style is overriding it, am not sure.

Comment: you can use firebug to see if styles get overridden, but since this style is inline, it should have the priority

Comment: i can see the style being applied for the row using developer toolbar, but it just doesn't seen to work!!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this still wont strikeout the entire text(even the white space between text/cells) in the row.

Comment: I've also tried this - e.Row.Font.Strikeout = true; but even this doesn't work!

Comment: the only way to "strike out the white space between the cells" is to have TEXT (in form of  ) in it. you can also try applying a background image to the row with a line through the middle to mimic the empty space strikeout.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put all your rows cell's content into <strike> tag. Example,

```
row.Cell[0].Text = "<strike>cell content from row.DataItem</strike>";
```

But it will only strike text in the cells. If you have cellpadding and cellspacing set to the row's table, then it might now look nice.

Comment: This just strikes out the text in the cell, i want to strikeout the entire row, even the whitespace between text/cells.

Comment: Those whitespace are there because of cellspacing, cellpadding, or margin applied to table. Send your HTML snippet of GridView, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
function oprt_OnRowDataBound(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.IsDeleted == true) {
        e.row.style.textDecorationLineThrough = true;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply in Grid view RowDataBound event write the below color, it 'll strikeout whole row in Grid view

```
If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Notes") <> "" Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Red
                e.Row.Font.Strikeout = True
End If
```

and it's working fine with me